# How to set relationship between parent and child?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have model `ArticleComments` and this is my relationships in model:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id');
    }

     public function parent()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ArticleComments','parent_id');
        }

        public function kids()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ArticleComments','parent_id','id');
        }
```

What i want is to get relationship `kids` and `user` something like this:

```
foreach($comments as $comment){
         $comment->kids->user = $comment->kids->user;
}
```

For now i only have for `parent` comments user like this:

```
  $comment->user=  $comment->user->personal_user;
```

So that in children comments i want user. Any suggestion how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting $comments? Are you using the model or DB::table('articleComments')?

Example of using Model:

```
$comments = \App\ArticleComments::where()->get();

foreach($comments as $comment)
{
   $kidsUser = $comment->kids->user;
}
```